# prism modularity / type exchange

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I'm trying to build an application based on codeplex prism unity. And I have a hard time understanding how to achieve a really loosely coupled application.

In my understanding a module ought to be a completely independent working part of an application. In other words an applicationen inside another one. Means there are no references from one developing project to another.

But how does the exchange between modules happen? I'm using the eventaggregator, which works fine, but I need a messagetype (the class that provides the data) in both the sending and the receiving module. If I want to work without referencing, I'm forced to duplicate the messagetype. I could use a third module, which provides the messagetype for both modules, but how can I use the messagetype without referencing the third module?

When I try to register the messagetype within the unity container, I still get a compiler error. It's obvious to me, because module a doesn't know the third module at compile time, neither does module b.

Am I experiencing the limitations of composite applications or do I miss a piece of the puzzle?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a third module for the common data classes.Create a common project for that classes and share it between the modules.
If you need to register any class , use Bootstrapper instead of a specific module.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that I should use the common referencing from the modules to my framework-dlls, is that correct? 

And if I would do so and the number of modules and framework-dlls would increase, there wouldn't be any advantage to the traditional way of tight coupling dlls, would there?

Comment: Yes, it will be tight coupled, but only for the shared data. You can also use shared service for accessing the common data. Create a singleton instance of the service and keep the shared data in that class.

Comment: Well, thanks for the idea, but I don't think it's the purpose of loosely coupled application to just offset the tight coupling from one place to another.

Comment: Please check 'Communicate Between Modules' section in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479(v=pandp.40).aspx. As i pointed earlier you can use shared service, it will be loosely coupled